# Cannot Append date field - getting NULL values

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, sql-server, append

I'm working on a standalone script that appends data from a SQL Server table onto an SDE db table. When working directly in ArcGIS Pro - the append works fine, but using a standalone script - dates are all null.  All other values from other fields are appending fine.  Any ideas on why dates won't come over?

Code Sample:

```
import arcpy, datetime, time

st = time.time()

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1


# Input variables
folderPath = r"S:\Data\MYfolder"
arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath + "\\" + "Archive as GIS.sde"
SQL_table = folderPath + "\\" + "vfiredepot03.sde\ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI"
Injury_table = folderPath + "\\" + "Archive as GIS.sde\Archive.GIS.VW_INJURY_PBI_"


# Table Processing
arcpy.management.TruncateTable(Injury_table)
arcpy.management.MakeTableView(Injury_table, "VW_INJURY_PBI__View", '', arcpy.env.workspace, "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;SHIFT SHIFT VISIBLE NONE;DEPT_ID DEPT_ID VISIBLE NONE;NAME NAME VISIBLE NONE;ITEM_NO ITEM_NO VISIBLE NONE;POSITION POSITION VISIBLE NONE;ACTIVITY ACTIVITY VISIBLE NONE;UNIT_ID UNIT_ID VISIBLE NONE;STATION STATION VISIBLE NONE;BATTALION BATTALION VISIBLE NONE;DIVISION DIVISION VISIBLE NONE;BEG_DT BEG_DT VISIBLE NONE;YEAR_MONTH YEAR_MONTH VISIBLE NONE;MONTH_YEAR MONTH_YEAR VISIBLE NONE;MONTH MONTH VISIBLE NONE;MONTH_NUM MONTH_NUM VISIBLE NONE;MONTH_SHORT MONTH_SHORT VISIBLE NONE;YEAR YEAR VISIBLE NONE;DATE DATE VISIBLE NONE;NINETY_DAYS NINETY_DAYS VISIBLE NONE;DAYS_ELAPSED DAYS_ELAPSED VISIBLE NONE;STANUM STANUM HIDDEN NONE")
arcpy.management.Append(SQL_TABLE, "VW_INJURY_PBI__View", "NO_TEST", 'SHIFT "SHIFT" true true false 1 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,SHIFT,0,1;DEPT_ID "DEPT_ID" true true false 6 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,DEPT_ID,0,6;NAME "NAME" true true false 39 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,NAME,0,39;ITEM_NO "ITEM_NO" true true false 5 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,ITEM_NO,0,5;POSITION "POSITION" true true false 2 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,POSITION,0,2;ACTIVITY "ACTIVITY" true true false 4 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,ACTIVITY,0,4;UNIT_ID "UNIT_ID" true false false 10 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,UNIT_ID,0,10;STATION "STATION" true true false 6 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,STATION,0,6;BATTALION "BATTALION" true true false 6 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,BATTALION,0,6;DIVISION "DIVISION" true true false 6 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,DIVISION,0,6;BEG_DT "BEG_DT" true true false 4 Long 0 10,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,BEG_DT,-1,-1;YEAR_MONTH "YEAR_MONTH" true true false 4000 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,YEAR_MONTH,0,4000;MONTH_YEAR "MONTH_YEAR" true true false 4000 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,MONTH_YEAR,0,4000;MONTH "MONTH" true true false 4000 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,MONTH,0,4000;MONTH_NUM "MONTH_NUM" true true false 4000 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,MONTH_NUM,0,4000;MONTH_SHORT "MONTH_SHORT" true true false 4000 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,MONTH_SHORT,0,4000;YEAR "YEAR" true true false 4000 Text 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,YEAR,0,4000;DATE "DATE" true true false 8 Date 0 0,First,#,ALPHA1.dbo.VW_INJURY_PBI,DATE,-1,-1;NINETY_DAYS "90 DAYS" true true false 1 Text 0 0,First,#;DAYS_ELAPSED "DAYS_ELAPSED" true true false 2 Short 0 5,First,#', '', '')

elapsed_time = time.time() - st
print ("Script Complete. Elapsed time: ", time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time)))
```

I'm using time and datetime in other steps in the script that are not shown here.

Comment: String math is an error waiting to happen (use `os.path.join` instead), and your code shouldn't work at all due to a lack of raw formatting in the path strings (backslash is escape).